# How to detect if the large object heap is causing the out of memory exception

Tags: .net, memory-management, out-of-memory, large-object-heap

I'm having System.OutOfMemory exceptions in my .NET Windows Service. I'm not sure what's causing it. I suspect fragmentation in the large object heap but i'm not sure. How can I verify my hypothesis?

I can use debuggers of all kinds, but what in the debugger should I look for?

Thanks

Comment: Have you initially tried debugging the source code for anything obvious?

Comment: Well, it's a given, you never get OOM on itty-bitty objects.  They always fit somewhere.  Use a memory profiler.  Test your service with real production data.  It will be twice as big next year, cover that too.

Answer (score 2):

[CLR Profiler](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=a362781c-3870-43be-8926-862b40aa0cd0&displaylang=en) is your friend for this.  It can attach to a Windows Service and gather all the metrics you need to find what's the culprit when your OOM hits.

Comment: What should I look for in the CLR Profiler that will let me know whether the cause is the large object heap or not?

Comment: For your particular scenario, I'd say start with the Final Heap Bytes histogram and then find what type of object is soaking up your memory.  From there, you can right-click and select Show Who Allocated and find which methods are allocating those large objects.

Comment: If the large object heap never grows above 60 MB, can it still be the cause of my out of memory exception

Comment: IF you have a lot of objects that get allocated and freed from it, YES.  The LOH is never compacted, so gaps could occur and there may be a point where just one more object can't fit in the gaps available.

Comment: @Jesse C. Slicer  - but if that was too happen, wouldn't the LOH appear large since .NET framework would expand it in order to fit the large object that currently can't fit? Or does does the large object heap counters only show the occupied space and not the free space?

Comment: @Jesse C. Slicer - "Large object heap size" counter is the current size in bytes, including the free space, of the Large Object Heap. So if the large object heap was causing an out of memory exception to be thrown you would expect the LOH to be pretty large would you not?

Comment: As I said - you can have (for example) 1GB free in the LOH, but the largest single chunk may be 200K.  If you try to allocate a 250K object, the 1GB free means nothing - there's no space big enough to hold it.  Search for "LOH fragmentation" for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this happens randomly and **never** when you are debugging on your machine, right?

What you can do is to create a dump and analyse the remains.

You need to turn to the true master of debugging, Tess. She is the Chuck Norris of debugging.

[Check this out, for example.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2009/04/16/net-exceptions-quick-windbg-sos-tip-on-how-to-dump-all-the-net-exceptions-on-the-heap.aspx)